# Writing data directly to Google Cloud Storage from Kubernetes pods

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub, google-kubernetes-engine

We are considering the alternatives to PubSub, due to high costs. For some of our low-value and high-volume data the PubSub can get quite expensive.

The plan of using PubSub:

- Run the service in Kubernetes pod
- Service pushes the data to PubSub
- We add a PubSub subscriber that reads the data from PubSub and writes it to GCS

The data has a very low-value. So even if we loose some small % of it (due to pod restarts, etc) that should not be a problem.

Is it possible to write the data directly to GCS or perhaps there are other less-expensive alternatives?

Edit: just to clarify, we don't need to write the data in real-time. We can write it in batches every few minutes or so.

Comment: does it have to be a bucket? can't be a persistent disk? I think with buckets you need to use gcefuse, which is in beta since forever.

Comment: @suren it has to be a bucket I'm afraid. Perhaps we can write to a local file and just push it to a bucket every few minutes?

Comment: a bucket is doable. From my experience gcefuse causes some troubles. I just wanted to see if an alternative is an option. But if not...

Comment: @suren what problems gcefuse causes? What are the alternatives? I guess we can just write file locally and push it to GCS one every 1+ minutes

Comment: I have seen authentication issues and mounting issues. I don't recall what it was exactly. But the fact that this product is not getting progressed, and still is in beta after about 2 years, worries me.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly write data to a bucket by mounting it by using gcefuse. You can read on how you can use gcefuse within GKE by following the directions [here](https://karlstoney.com/2017/03/01/fuse-mount-in-kubernetes/).

Comment: `gcefuse` is names `gcsfuse` now.